# Throw [Errno 13] when docker-compose build

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: ./manage.py runserver 
    container_name: report_service
    volumes:
      - .:/report_service
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /report_service

WORKDIR /report_service

ADD . /report_service/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Why throw this error? When i local build on Mac OS it's okey but if on production (ubuntu) error.

```
root@services:~/services/generation_report# docker-compose build
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/appdirs.cpython-36.pyc.139931671694792'
Check the permissions.

ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running `docker-compose build` with `sudo`? Also have you tried running `pip install` without the `--user` flag?

Comment: Try both, not working

Comment: Try switching to `python:3.7` or `python:3.8`, assuming your application supports them. Also please post the contents of your `requirements.txt` file. Also try switching application folder to `/usr/report_service`. You can skip `RUN mkdir ...` just use `WORKDIR /usr/report_service` it will automatically create directory if it does not exist.